# ng-repeat causing unwanted positioning side-effects

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an angular directive that is creating twitter bootstrap popover dynamically:

```
app.directive("detailsPopup", function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: { items: '='},
    template: '<i ng-click="onClick($event)">click me</i>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.onClick = function(e) {
            var html
            // with ng-repeat:
            html = '<div ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</div>';
            // without ng-repeat:
            //html = '<div>AAA</div><div>BBB</div><div>CCC</div><div>DDD</div>';
            $(e.target).popover({
                trigger: "manual", content: function() {                           
                    return $compile(html)(scope);
                }, html: true
            }).popover("show")
        };
    }
```

When ng-repeat is used, the popover is not positioned correctly. When it is not used, all works as normal. Why is ng-repeat causing unwanted positioning side-effects? Any ideas how to fix that?

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vfw4v0Le/

UPDATE: Not wanting to use additional library (AngularUI) the following approach worked for me:

```
app.directive("detailsPopup", function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: { items: '='},
    template: '<i ng-click="onClick($event)">click me</i>' +
        '<div class="hidden"><div ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}}</div></div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.onClick = function(e) {
            $(e.target).popover({
                    trigger: "manual", content: function() {
                        return $(e.target).next("div").clone(true).removeClass("hidden")
                    }, html: true
                }).popover("show")
        };
    }
}});
```

So we are evaluating the whole popup content at the time the main page is built, just making it hidden. When showing the popup we are cloning the relevant content.

Comment: Your fiddle has an error (check the console) because the `items` attribute of your directives expects a variable, but is given an expression.

Comment: yeah, it does behave as expected, though, the array items are iterated over properly in the ng-repeat

Answer (score 2):

In the case of the ng-repeat, the popover is shown before its content is rendered, since it is dynamic. Therefore the popover is positioned (using top-left coordinates) as if it was empty, then the content appears, making it the position not right. The **[Angular UI Bootstap project](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap)** includes a **[directive for Bootstrap popovers](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover)**. According to the [source code](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/tooltip/tooltip.js), re-positioning the popover to adapt to the dynamic content is not an easy task. You would be better off directly using **their ready-made directive**.